# Abrir ventana de un JFrame dentro del mismo JFrame

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, interfaz-gráfica

Buen Dia Amigos,

tengo un Jframe llamado principal,

y tengo otro JFrame llamado activar_alarma, este frame contiene:

1. en la interfaz, una tabla con un aviso que deseo mostrar cuando un timer.schedule se active en una fecha determinada.
2. tambien contiene un metodo que es el que llamo para que activen o programen esos timer.schedule

---

para poner un ejemplo, digamoslo asi: mi frame (activar alarma) actua como "clase"(siendo un frame), porque lo digo:, Porque desde el otro frame (principal), primero llamo al metodo que hay dentro de mi frame (sin abrir la ventana), y luego dentro de ese metodo quiero abrir la ventana del mismo frame desde donde estoy ejecutando en metodo.

Dentro del Jframe activar_alarma quiero que se abra este mismo JFrame activar_alarma, NO haciendolo asi:

```
new activar_alarmas_vencimiento().setVisible(true);
```

y asi no me funciona me saca error

```
 activar_alarmas_vencimiento.setVisible(true);
```

### non-static method setVisible(boolean) cannot be referenced from a static context

(Alt-Enter shows hints)

ya que me lo abre como nuevo perdiendo el proceso que ya llevo, solo quiero que me habra la ventana o se haga visible dentro de mi metodo.

O como puedo hacer para que se abra pero invisible pero que al momento de ejecutar mi metodo,se haga visible solo adentro de mi metodo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deantemano GRACIAS.

Comment: No entiendo bien lo que quieres decir, no se si lo que quieres es abrir una nueva ventana, que se abra por encima de la que ya tienes, que en vez de un JFrame seria un JDialog. o cambiar El JPanel de tu JFrame por otro.  cada una de las cosas tiene un proceso distinto. lo de la ventana por encima de la otra puede hacerlo de una manera no muy correcta con JFrame .setAlwaysOnTop(true);  pero te vuelvo a decir, no he entendido bien lo que necesitas.

Comment: @ALBERTOPERALTA hola alberto, lo que ocurre es que mi frame digamoslo asi,como para poner un ejemplo actua como "clase"(siendo un frame, porque lo digo asi, Porque desde otro frame, primero llamo al metodo que hay dentro de mi frame sin abrir la ventana, y luego dentro de ese metodo quiero abrir la ventana de mi frame... espero me haya echo entender mejor.

Comment: como Bien comenta @AlbertoLopez puedes hacer el metodo consultar alarmas como metodo estatico. aunque viendo tu codigo te aconsejo que instancies la clase. hagas un activar_alarmas_vendimento activarAlarmas =  new activar_alarmas_vendimento();  activarAlarmas.consultar_alarmas();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

por si alguien le sirve lo solucione asi: 
con un metodo en el mismo frame

```
public void abrir(){
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
```

y lo llame dentro de mi frame en un TimerTask

```
TimerTask tarea =new TimerTask(){
                @Override
                public void run() {     
                    abrir();
                    //llame a un metodo que lo ponga visible  
                    //sonar a larma y dar aviso
                    label1.setText("EL PRODUCTO: "+nom_producto+" ESTA POR VENCER");
                    label2.setText("LA FECHA DE CADUCIDAD ES: "+fecha_caducidad);
                    label3.setText("DESCRIPCION: "+aviso);
                    cod_alarma_tabla.setText(cod_alarma);
                    llamarAudio();
                }
            };
```

ya que el timerTask tiene un metodo, lo consegui llamando al metodo, pero si no es asi , lo pueden poner solo

```
this.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Los métodos "no estáticos" de la clase activar_alarmas_vencimiento no puedes accesarlos si no instancias esa clase.  Hay dos formas de solucionarlo:

1) Los métodos que quieres usar de esa clase sin que la clase esté instanciada los tendrás que declarar estáticos. Y ver si se puede y si conviene.

2) Puedes instanciar la clase activar_alarmas_vencimiento, que entiendo que es un JFrame. Ese JFrame no se va a mostrar hasta que lo hagas visible con el método setVisible(true).  Así que si requieres usar métodos no estáticos instancia la clase y usa sus métodos, y cuando la quieras hacer visible, la haces visible.

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas, intente instansiarla y lo que hacia era correr el intComponent(); y borraba lo que ya habia echo inclusive poniendolo en diferentes lugares, al final lo logre solo asi : cree un metodo y adentro le puse this.setVisible(true). ... y lo llame cuando se ejecuto a tarea. no crei que fuera tan sencillo y todo lo que me demore. avecesempiezas por lo mas dificil. pero el todo es aprender.